# Django migration: "0001_initial.py" dependency error

Tags: python, django, migration, database-migration, django-migrations

I just started to work on someone else's project which uses Django.

After running this sequence:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

I got the error:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: 
Migration structures.0002_auto_20171121_1034 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('structures', '0001_initial')
```

The `migrations` folder contains:
`0002_auto_20171121_1034.py`,
`0003_auto_xxxxxxxx_xxxx.py`,
`0004_auto_xxxxxxxx_xxxx.py`,
`0005_auto_xxxxxxxx_xxxx.py`,
`0006_auto_xxxxxxxx_xxxx.py`,
`0007_auto_xxxxxxxx_xxxx.py`.

But it doesn't contain `0001_initial.py`.

**What I tried:**

**1)** I tried to delete all `.pyc` files of `migrations` folder.

**2)** I tried to remove these three lines:

```
dependencies = [
    ('structures', '0001_initial'),
]
```

contained in `0002_auto_20171121_1034.py`, but, this time, I got this error:

```
You have 6 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations 
for app(s): structures.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Is there anyone who could help me?

Answer (score 0):

it maybe rised with adding or dropping a field of model. Try the upper answer.

Comment: Sorry, which "upper answer" do you mean? Can you give more details?

Comment: Your data must be reserved? otherwise, you can try droping all the migration files, then redo makemigrations and migrate. It is my experience.